# C++: Why cout is printing carriage return with the strings read from a file using ifstream?

Tags: c++, output, ifstream

I'm trying to read a file **capitals** with contents as follows:

```
Tokyo   
33200000
New York    
17800000
Sao Paulo   
17700000
Seoul
17500000
Mexico City
17400000
```

The code snippet I'm using to print the file contents is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    std::ifstream ifs("capitals");
    std::string s, s2;

    while (getline(ifs, s)) {
        getline(ifs, s2);
        cout << s  << ": "
             << s2 << endl;
    } 

    return 0;
}
```

But, the output I'm getting is as follows:

```
code_master5@Brahmaastra:~$ g++ test.cpp -std=c++17
code_master5@Brahmaastra:~$ ./a.out 
: 33200000
: 17800000  
: 17700000  
: 17500000
: 17400000y
```

The expected output should be of form:

```
Tokyo: 33200000
```

The last line of the original output suggests that cout is printing **carriage return** after printing the city name. Why is this happening?

**EDIT 1:**  As suggested by **@Qubit** I used pop_back() to remove last character. The changed code is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    std::ifstream ifs("capitals");
    std::string s, s2;

    while (getline(ifs, s)) {
        s.pop_back();
        getline(ifs, s2);
        s2.pop_back();
        cout << s  << ": "
             << s2 << endl;
    } 

    return 0;
}
```

The output now is:

```
Tokyo   : 33200000
New York    : 17800000
Sao Paulo   : 17700000
Seoul: 17500000
Mexico City: 17400000
```

What are these extra spaces?

**EDIT 2** The problem is solved now. As suggested by **@lubgr**, this is happening because the file is stored in windows-style with \r at end of each line. So, I installed **dos2unix** and ran the following command:

```
code_master5@Brahmaastra:~$ dos2unix capitals 
dos2unix: converting file capitals to Unix format...
```

Then, as further explained by @codekaizer, I kept those pop_back() calls to remove the trailing '\t' characters to get the expected output.

Comment: Getline also stores the new line character at the end, you should pop_back() to get rid of it and then try printing.

Comment: @Qubit It worked, but still there are unnecessary spaces in the output! Let me add the output...

Comment: @code_master5, is *"unnecessary spaces"* a `\t` character?

Comment: @codekaizer yeah! it is. Thanks. That means two back to back pop_backs now!

Comment: Consider using a `trim()` like function to remove unwanted leading/trailing whitespace from strings. Then you don't need to modify the file itself.

Comment: @Qubit -- `getline` does **not** store the new line character. The problem, as the edit shows, is that the input file is not in the proper format, so all bets are off.

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but do you really need the extra stuff that `std::endl` does? `'\n'` ends a line.

Comment: @PeteBecker What extra stuff related to std::endl you're talking about? Just curious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is caused by your `capitals` file, it has line ending with a carriage return (windows style), but when you print it in a non-Windows terminal, these carriage returns aren't properly handled. You have two options, either run

```
dos2unix captials
```

which will remove all carriage return characters from the line endings, or as suggested by @Qubit in the comments, you get rid of the last character inside the while loop:

```
while (getline(ifs, s)) {
    getline(ifs, s2);
    s.pop_back();
    s2.pop_back();

    /* ... */
}
```

Comment: Thanks! the reason you're stating is the one. Although the in the code, I still had to keep those pop_back() to remove \t as suggested by @codekaizer in the comments above.

Comment: @code_master5 You can also edit the file and remove the tabs that you don't want to have there. Depends on your situation though, whether it makes more sense to adjust the character data in the code reading/writing the file or in the file itself.